# Corrupted tooltips on Ubuntu 18.04.3

Tags: tooltip

Since a few weeks i have an issue with incorrectly displayed tooltips.
Does anyone else here have the same problem and know a solution to fix this?

[Tooltip in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgHqD.png)

[Tooltip in VLC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohScm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed it for me:
`sudo apt install xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-video-all`